# Using async function in sync function

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

I have an httpClient with async() methods, I need to use in sync methods called from the GUI thread. I cannot use the .Result property of the task because it causes a deadlock and freezes the GUI.

I have a solution with launching a new thread pool thread and executing an async method in it:

```
Task.Run(async () => { ApiInfo = await _apiClient.Get<ApiInfo>($"{Url}"); }).Wait();
```

This works, but because I'm new to async programming - I'm not sure if it's the preferred way for my situation?

Comment: Sounds like you should just embrace async and redesign a little

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't edit the interfaces of these classes.

Comment: You shouldn't need to edit the underlying method signatures, you can just call them using the static helper class.